# Centering a Nav-bar that's also a hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I copied a hamburger menu with some nice animations, did some adjustments for it to fit into my site, for mobile. Now i'm trying to make that menu get out of the hamburger and into the middle of the screen for desktop. What i'm running into is the menu having really wierd positioning and normal "centering" such as justify-content and others do not work. I also tried putting it into a grid, but with no luck. I'll paste my html and css here and hope you can give me any help, wheter it is how I can center it or just re-writeing things so it works.

What i'm trying to accomplish is the menu being a hamburger for phone and for desktop it should be a "normal" nav-bar centered at the bottom of the site, responsive.

I'm kind of new so it could be kind of janky but yea... :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #262626;

  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;

  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#backdrop {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;

  background-color: #727365;
}

#home-link {
  color: #f2f2e4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;

  position: absolute;
  top: 1.95rem;
  left: 2.6rem;
}

/* Hamburger menu */
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3f403b;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #0c0c0c;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: block;

  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem;
  right: 3rem;

  z-index: 1;
}

#menu-checkbox {
  display: block;

  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;

  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu-toggle span {
  display: block;

  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;

  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: #f2f2e4;
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 1;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
    opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menu-toggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menu-toggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #3f403b;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 70vh;

  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;

  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;

  background-color: #bfbfae;
  list-style: none;

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 13px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
}

/* Media queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #backdrop {
    width: 98%;
    height: 95.5%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }

  #menu-checkbox {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu-toggle span {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    transform: none !important;

    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;

    position: absolute;
    top: 97vh;
    right: 38.2vw;

    border-radius: 1rem;

    height: fit-content;
    width: max-content;
  }

  #menu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #home-link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: static;

    padding-top: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>OVERCASTING</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="script/js.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@200;300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="backdrop">
        <header id="wrapper">
          <nav>
            <a href="index.html" id="home-link">OVERCASTING</a>
            <div id="menu-toggle">
              <input id="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
              <span class="hamburger-span"></span>
              <span class="hamburger-span"></span>
              <span class="hamburger-span"></span>
              <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't need the `ul#menu` to be inside the `div#menu-toggle` consider taking it out into the `header#wrapper`. another solution would be to use `position: fixed`

Comment: Position: fixed; could be a option but how do i get it centered and responsive?

Comment: To center an element on the x-axis you can use `right: 50%;` `translate:50% 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #262626;

  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;

  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#backdrop {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;

  background-color: #727365;
}

#home-link {
  color: #f2f2e4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;

  position: absolute;
  top: 1.95rem;
  left: 2.6rem;
}

/* Hamburger menu */
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3f403b;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #0c0c0c;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: block;

  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem;
  right: 3rem;

  z-index: 1;
}

#menu-checkbox {
  display: block;

  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;

  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu-toggle span {
  display: block;

  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;

  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: #f2f2e4;
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 1;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
    opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menu-toggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menu-toggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #3f403b;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 70vh;

  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;

  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;

  background-color: #bfbfae;
  list-style: none;

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menu-checkbox:checked ~ ul {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 13px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgb(109, 109, 109);
}

/* Media queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #backdrop {
    width: 98%;
    height: 95.5%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }

  #menu-checkbox {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu-toggle span {
    display: none;
  }

  #menu {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
    transform: none !important;

    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;

    position: absolute;
    top: 97vh;
    right: 38.2vw;

    border-radius: 1rem;

    height: fit-content;
    width: max-content;
  }

  #menu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #home-link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: static;

    padding-top: 0.5rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
#menu-toggle {
    right: unset;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
#menu {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: unset;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>OVERCASTING</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="script/js.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@200;300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="backdrop">
        <header id="wrapper">
          <nav>
            <a href="index.html" id="home-link">OVERCASTING</a>
            <div id="menu-toggle">
              <input id="menu-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
              <span class="hamburger-span"></span>
              <span class="hamburger-span"></span>
              <span class="hamburger-span"></span>
              <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

How does this look?

I've added the following CSS at the end of your CSS block

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #menu-toggle {
        right: unset;
        position: relative;
        top: -30px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
    #menu {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
        right: unset;
    }
}
```